# animate creating a full rotate loop

Tags: jquery, loops, rotation, jquery-animate

i creat a fish animation and i want him to complete a full (circle) rotation

```
function anim() {
    $(".fish_wrap").animate({
        "left": "-90px" }, 5000);    
}
anim();

function AnimateRotate(d){
    var elem = $(".fish_wrap");

    $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: d}, {
        duration: 9000,
        step: function(now){
            elem.css({
                 transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
            });
        }
    });
}

AnimateRotate(120);

$(".fish_wrap")
.css({top:200,position:'absolute'})
.animate({top:0}, 8000, function() {

});
```

here is the fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/TxC5y/4/